# g++ does not recognize -stdlib=libstdc++

Tags: c++, gcc

So I just reinstall gcc using home brew, when I compile a programme and try to use libstdc++... I get a error:

```
dhcp-18-189-47-44:openmp_code myname$ g++-4.8 -fopenmp tmp2.cpp -stdlib=libstdc++
g++-4.8: error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libstdc++'
```

Someone has idea what is happening ? Thank you.

Comment: g++4.8 used libstdc++ as the standard library by default. So, you need not specify this option at all.

Comment: `-stdlib` is a clang flag. For e.g., look here: https://libcxx.llvm.org/UsingLibcxx.html#using-libc-when-it-is-not-the-system-default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message clearly says, g++ does not support `-stdlib` as an option. You can simply remove that option from the command line.

```
g++-4.8 -fopenmp tmp2.cpp
```

should be all you need.